# Porque eu tenho que clicar duas vezes para ser criada uma imagem?

Tags: javascript

```js
function myCanvas() {
    var c = document.querySelector('#myCanvas');
    var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = 'https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_the_scream.jpg';

    ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="650" height="600" style="border:1px solid black;overflow: scroll;"></canvas>
<br>
<button onclick="myCanvas()">Click</button>
```

No trecho de código acima eu preciso clicar duas vezes para ser criada uma imagem dentro do elemento `<canvas>` porque isso está acontecendo? eu quero que no primeiro click ele já crie uma imagem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que acontece é que a imagem leva um tempo para carregar, então você está mandando desenhar no `<canvas>` antes de saber **o que** desenhar de fato. Na segunda vez funciona pois você já tinha baixado a imagem e ela ficou no cache.

Para resolver isso, mande desenhar no `<canvas>` após o `load` (carregamento) da imagem. Existe um exemplo similar na [documentação do MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Using_images#Creating_an_image_from_scratch).

```js
function myCanvas() {
    var c = document.querySelector('#myCanvas');
    var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
    var img = new Image();

    img.onload = function () {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10); 
    };

    img.src = 'https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_the_scream.jpg';
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="650" height="600" style="border:1px solid black;overflow: scroll;"></canvas>
<br>
<button onclick="myCanvas()">Click</button>
```

É recomendado colocar o `.onload` antes de indicar o `.src` para não correr o risco da imagem ser baixada antes do `.onload` ser atribuído, pois caso isso acontecesse, o `.onload` nunca seria executado.